# Importing a jQuery plugin into a React component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, parceljs

For reasons I won't get into, I need to use [Spectrum.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spectrum-colorpicker) within a React component. However, I can't make it behave.

I installed both jQuery and Spectrum via `npm install -D jquery spectrum-colorpicker` and I'm trying to import them into the component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import spectrum from 'spectrum-colorpicker';
```

jQuery works as intended but I can't get Spectrum to do it's thing. I always get `TypeError: $(...).spectrum is not a function` as it seems Spectrum is undefined.

I'm very new to React so I'm sure I'm just doing something obviously wrong. I tried Googling but nothing I came across helped. FWIW, I'm also doing this to initialize Spectrum:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('#custom').spectrum({ color: '#f00' });
}
```

On the off chance this is also important, I'm using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) as my bundler.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I don't think it is a good idea to use jQuery or any jQuery plugin in React at all. There are a lot of alternatives which are build specifically for React which are plug and play.

The problem with using both is that there is an overlap in what they do. React assumes that nothing else is modifying the DOM, which can have unexpected results.

It looks like the Spectum you are using doesn't have React package itself, but there are a lot of alternatives (For example: https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color). I created a stackblitz to demonstrate the code as well (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rme3f4?embed=1&file=Hello.js).

I hope this will work better for your example. It's a little getting used to it, but there is good documentation and I think it will make a lot of sense when you start using it.

Comment: I'm aware of the alternatives but in this instance I very much need to use Spectrum. Getting jQuery to work was pretty easy but Spectrum remains unavailable.